# Function by string in javascript and SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error

I create a let calc = new Function(`return ${strExpression};`); I want to check syntax of calc before run or caught SyntaxError raised by calc();

I tried:

```
function compute(strExpression){
    let calc = new Function(`return ${strExpression};`);
    try {
            result = calc();
            return result;
        } catch (error) {
            return null;
        } 
}
```

For some invaild strExpression I could get an error and in this case I see SyntaxError on console but catch doesn't work.

Comment: The syntax error from invalid code is thrown by the `Function` call, not the `calc` call. Put everthing within the `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see an error from

```
let calc = Function("some code");
```

because the given string is not valid code.

You could move the line into the `try` block and catch the error.

```js
var result = function() {
    try {
        let calc = Function("some code");
        result = calc();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
}();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I used to think it's gotta be `new Function(...)`. No need to explicitly call the constructor using `new`?

Comment: it works both, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Answer (score 1):

I changed my answer based your updated question. Then completely code block from where may arise exception should keep inside try block like following:

```
function compute(strExpression){
  try {
      let calc = new Function(`return ${strExpression};`);
      result = calc();
      return result;
  } catch (error) {
      return null;
  }
```

}

But you should also keep in mind few things. What will be happen if I call above function with empty parameter like following?

```
console.log(compute());
```

There you expecting should go in `catch` block but reality is NO. Because parameter is `undefined` so this is also one kind of datatype in JS so no in `catch` block. So you should also these type issue when you using `try catch`.